# Null pointer access

Tags: java, matrix, nullpointerexception, instantiation, abstract

I got this method to multiply 2 matrices:

```
public static AbstractMatrix multiplication(AbstractMatrix m1, AbstractMatrix m2) {
    AbstractMatrix result = null;
    int sum=0;
    if (m1.getNbc() == m2.getNbl()) {
        for(int c=0;c<m1.getNbl();c++){
            for(int d=0;d<m2.getNbc();d++){
                for(int k=0;k<m1.getNbc();k++){
                    sum=somme+m1.getValeur(c, k)*m2.getValeur(k, d);
                }
                result.setValeur(c, d, sum);
                sum=0;
            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting a:

> null pointer access the variable result can only be null

at this location: `result.set()` . I know that the problem is in `AbstractMatrix result=null;` but `AbstractMAtrix` is an abstract class so I can't instantiate it (`new AbstractMatrix`).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried instantiating any class that `extends` the abstract class `result`?

Comment: the instantiation works without a problem, i have ,MapMatrix,2DMatrix,and yeah ,all of this work,but here in the argument of this method igot to put AbstractMatrix

Comment: one thing you could do is to change the interface to `public static void multiplication(AbstractMatrix m1, AbstractMatrix m2, AbstractMatrix r)` and do `r = new SomeMatrixType()` from where you call `multiplication` since there you know the class the result should belong to

Comment: @Pika if my answer has helped you solve your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1):

You correctly identified your problem -> you are trying to call a method on `null` which obviously cannot be done.
Also, you correctly identified that `AbstractMatrix` is an `abstract` class and therefore cannot be instantiated.

> What needs to be done to remedy this?

You must create a subclass, let's say `Matrix extends AbstractMatrix` which overrides any `abstract` methods in `AbstractMatrix`. Then you may instantiate it like so:

```
AbstractMatrix result = new Matrix();
```

This will make your code run correctly and will not throw an NPE.

Comment: yes thanks,but i think that i will have another problem here,cause here i need the setValeur method,and this method is an abstract one in AbstractMatrix and i have to override it in every subcalss that extends AbstractMatrix depending on the type of the matri,cause here i got the Mapmatrix,1D MAtrix,2D Matrix,i have also ArrayListMatrix,,but in matrix class like u said,i don't know how to override the setValeur method

Comment: That is not a problem. If you have `setValeur` implemented in your `abstract` class then you can use it in **all** of its subclasses without needing to override it. If your `setValeur` is also `abstract` then you **will** need to override it in each subclass of `AbstractMatrix` indeed in order for your program to work correctly.

Comment: setValeur is an abstract method in AbstracMatrix,and i have to override it every subclass

Comment: So yes, like I said, there is no other way besides overriding it if you want to use it. Or you can make it not `abstract` and then you will just have it available to use in all your subclasses.

Comment: yes,but the problem is that this method depend on the type of the matrix,cause it's not the same setValeur in MapMatrix and 2DMatrix,if u see what i mean,and if i put it in class matrix i don't know the structure and how to access the data to change it

Comment: I see. You will have to rethink your design of your classes or this multiplication method. If you have different implementations of `setValeur`  in each subclass then you can also check with `instanceof` and use the correct instantiation (and then implementation) of `AbstractMatrix` as you wish.

Comment: thanks ,but another problem that's not my design,it's a homework and it's the teacher's design

Comment: You will have to consult your teacher. I have given you plenty of options to re-write your code in order for it to work. Choose one or try to think of a workaround (or edit your question with **all** the relevant information).